# rails 4 has_many association bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i have an simple setup for a `has_many` association:

```
def Account
   has_many :timers
end

def Timer
  belongs_to :timer
end
```

if i try to build a timer i get this false behavior:

```
account.id => 1
account.timers.build => #<Timer id: nil, account_id: 0>
```

...of course it should be:

```
account.id => 1
account.timers.build => #<Timer id: nil, account_id: 1>
```

Because it's rails4 in tried the same with a fresh setup. and it ***works!***

gems: `pg, haml-rails, devise, simple_form, globalize3`

***Question:*** what could be the cause of breaking the Rails API ?

Answer (score 0):

and the winner is:

`gem 'globalize3', github: 'harlock/globalize3', branch: 'rails4-wip'`